# API authorization with comman token set in postman header laravel

Tags: laravel, api, token

How to **set common token dynamic for all other API** when login API call in laravel?

Comment: Are you talking about setting a dynamic token in postman?

Comment: I mean unique generated token for each user which manually i set  for each and every route in headers on Postman  .If i want to set this unique token only once which will call on every route.So what is good way any idea?

Comment: You can create an environment and variables for that purpose. Check It out here: https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/variables-and-environments/variables/